# Does every thread store its context in a separate PCB?

Tags: operating-systems

Is a thread's context stored in the process's PCB, or is a new PCB created for the thread?

Comment: The P stands for process, not for thread. This answers your question.

Comment: Right... so is there a different data structure used to store a thread's context and link it to the PCB?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_control_block

Answer (score 2):

A thread is the unit of execution of a process. The latter can have one or more threads. Each thread, shares the common process info (global variables, files, address space), but it has its own computation and therefore stores independently PC, stack pointer, IP, and other registers. All this information is stored in the **TCB** (thread control block), whereas the process stores the information in the **PCB** (process control block).
The way you link them together is by saving inside the thread's TCB, a reference to the process that spawned the thread.

For example, this is the implementation of the TCB for the Pintos operating system, written in C:

```
 struct thread {
    /* Owned by thread.c. */
    tid_t tid;                 /* Thread identifier. */
    enum thread_status status; /* Thread state. */
    char name[16];             /* Name (for debugging purposes). */
    uint8_t *stack;            /* Saved stack pointer. */
    int priority;              /* Priority. */
    struct list_elem allelem;  /* List element for all threads list. */

    /* Shared between thread.c and synch.c. */
    struct list_elem elem; /* List element. */

    /* Advanced scheduler fields. */
    int recent_cpu; /* In fixed point format.  */
    int nice;
    bool update_priority_needed;

    /* Donated priorities */
    struct donated_priorities donated_priorities;

    /* Lock this thread is trying to acquire */
    struct lock *lock_sought;

#ifdef USERPROG
    /* Owned by userprog/process.c. */
    uint32_t *pagedir; /* Page directory. */
    spt spt;
#endif

    struct process* process;
    /* Owned by thread.c. */
    unsigned magic; /* Detects stack overflow. */
};
```

Note the process pointer, right at the end of the struct.